# mouse eventlistener isnt being removed

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

Im trying to remove an eventlistener that I initialize somewhere in the code and then remove later in a function. I know that you have to remove the same listener that you initialized, but it doesnt seem to be working. I store the eventlistener in a variable that I believe has global scope, so Im not sure what the issue is. The eventlistener itself works fine, and starts as expected.

I have also tried not storing the eventlistener in a variable but that didnt work either.

```
  mainFunction = function (){
    mousee = document.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseEvent);
    if ($(".message_input").val().replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0){
      unbindAll(true); // unbind all functions
      message = getMessageText();  // retrieve the users message text
      $(".message_input_wrapper").html("");
      printMessage(message, "right"); // display there message on the screen
      if (message=="stop"){
        document.removeEventListener(mousee);
        initiateStopSection();
      } else {
        //async_elipsis();
        response = async_bot(message);
      };
    };
  };
```

Just for clarification, I was initially using

```
document.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseEvent)
```

but it wasnt working

Comment: `document.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseEvent)`

Answer (score 0):

When using removeEventListener, you have to pass the event type and the event handler, so in this case you would use

```js
document.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeEventListener` takes 2 arguments.  The first is the event you are trying to target, in this case `mouseout`, and the second is the function you wish to remove.

For your example it would be this:

```
document.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseEvent)
```

There is no need to set the initial listener to a variable with this implementation.

Comment: I tried that also, but that didnt work for me either.

Comment: Then I would look at the if condition to make sure it is being met.  The syntax for removing the event listener is correct here.  Does `initiateStopSection` get called?

Comment: yeah, the rest of the statement is running fine

Comment: This would take some more hands-on debugging then.  We might need to see more of the code in order to help you.  Or better yet, if you can reproduce the issue in a code snippet embedded in your question we would see exactly what is going wrong.